Symfony 6 Form Login: The key "email" must be a string, "NULL" given
I encountered the following error while working with Symfony 6.4, React, API Platform, and LexikJWTAuthentication. I've successfully secured my API with JWT, which works perfectly. Now, I'm aiming to implement a user login that redirects to the dashboard. 
However, I'm facing an issue: "The key 'email' must be a string, 'NULL' given."
I've configured everything in security.yml and in React. I've found a similar thread, but no solution was provided. Any ideas?
security.yml:
security:
  enable_authenticator_manager: true
  password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
  providers:
    app_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: email

  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/{_{profiler|wdt}}/
      security: false

    login:
      pattern: ^/api/login
      stateless: true
      form_login:
        check_path: /api/login_check
        username_parameter: email
        password_parameter: password
        default_target_path: app_dashboard
        success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
        failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

    api:
      pattern:   ^/api/
      stateless: true
      jwt: ~

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }


when@test:
  security:
    password_hashers:
      Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
        algorithm: auto
        cost: 4
        time_cost: 3
        memory_cost: 10

lexik_jwt_authentication.yml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    token_ttl: 3600

    api_platform:
        check_path: /api/login_check
        username_path: email
        password_path: security.credentials.password

Login.jsx
const Login = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    const handleEmailChange = (e) => setEmail(e.target.value);
    const handlePasswordChange = (e) => setPassword(e.target.value);

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(
                'https://localhost/index.php/api/login_check',
                {email, password},
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                }
            );
            console.log('Login successful:', response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during login:', error);
        }
    };
return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Input
            type="email"
            variant="bordered"
            size="lg"
            label="Email"
            placeholder="Enter your email"
            labelPlacement="outside"
            className="pt-5 pb-5"
            value={email}
            id="email"
            name="_email"
            onChange={handleEmailChange}
        />
        <Input
            type="password"
            variant="bordered"
            size="lg"
            label="Password"
            placeholder="Enter your password"
            labelPlacement="outside"
            className="pt-5 pb-12"
            value={password}
            id="password"
            name="_password"
            onChange={handlePasswordChange}
        />
        <CustomButton label="Login" type="submit"/>
    </form>
)
            

The interesting part is, that on the request email and password are not empty at all
{"email":"admin@test.com","password":"test"}


if you use symfony 6.4 you should use this configuration in your security.yml file https://symfony.com/bundles/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/current/index.html#symfony-5-3-and-higher. In addition, in your code here:
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },

You use "application/json", you should check your file which is in config/packages/api_platform.yaml.
api_platform:
    title: Hello API Platform
    version: 1.0.0
    formats:
        jsonld: ['application/ld+json']
     //The other parameters of your api

To see if the format accepted by your api is json and not ld+json.
